# Crystal Reports page numbering

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1, page-numbering

I am using CR to create a catalogue from multiple sales quotes. I will print these multiple quotes into a binder as a sales catalogue.

My issue is that the page numbering needs to start at a different value based upon the quote's final place in the catalogue. I have the following formula referencing a UDF on the sales order header

```
{OQUT.U_CatPageNo} as the starting page number: -

IF PageNumber = 1 Then 
   {OQUT.U_CatPageNo}
Else
   {OQUT.U_CatPageNo}+PageNumber-1
```

This works fine on both the left and right side of the page footer. My issue comes when trying to suppress the number based upon whether it is a left or right facing page. I am using the following formula: -

```
IF {OQUT.U_GLKREF} = 'L' Then PageNumber MOD 2 = 1
```

`{OQUT.U_GLKREF}` indicates whether it is a 'L' for left or 'R' for right-facing page however, the syntax seems to be ignoring the `{OQUT.U_GLKREF} = 'L'` segment.

Comment: can you add a picture to understand more

Comment: Try to put an "else" statement because the undefined return when is 'R' may be misleading you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some rest time and clearer thing I think I have solved it this way: -

For the left page i'm using: -

IF{OQUT.U_GLKREF} = 'R' Then PageNumber MOD 2 = 1
Else
PageNumber MOD 2 = 0

For the right page i'm using: -

IF {OQUT.U_GLKREF} = 'L' Then PageNumber MOD 2 = 1

It seems to be solid so far.